# Auto capitalize first letter of a sentence using draft-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using Reactjs and draftjs libraries to create a rich text editor. I want to auto-capitalize the first letter of a sentence.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} 
        autoCapitalize="sentences"/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The component that I've created doesn't auto capitalize after period. Why isn't the auto-capitalization not working? Is there any better ways to make it work?

Comment: where is the autocapitalize function?

Comment: it's an inbuilt feature of draft-js editor component. link:https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor.html#content

Comment: Those docs and the MDN linked from them say its delegated to a browser feature that is non standard, could it be that your browser you are testing in doesn't support it?

Comment: I'm using Google chrome and safari

Comment: it might be easier to make your own auto capitalization with the onChange function if you use a regex and just replace the first character after the period with itself but upperCased.

Answer (score 1):

I just found myself in the same situation with Draft.js: needing to implement autocapitalization, but finding that the in-built Draft prop does nothing, so I made my own methods to achieve this.

1. This is a utility function I created to query the characters before the cursor in Draft.js:

   ```
   const getCharsPrecedingFocus = (
     contentState: any,
     selectionState: any,
     numberOfChars: number,
   ): string => {
     const currentBlock =
       contentState.getBlockForKey(selectionState.getAnchorKey());
     const currentBlockText = currentBlock.getText();
     const endOfText = selectionState.getEndOffset();

     return currentBlockText.slice(
       endOfText - numberOfChars,
       endOfText,
     );
   };
   ```
2. Now we can check if there's a character at the start of a new sentence which should be capitalized. Put this code in your `handleBeforeInput` method which is passed as a prop:

   ```
   const handleBeforeInput = (chars: string, editorState: any) => {
     const NON_CAPITALISED_REGEX = /^(?:\.\s)([a-z])$/;

     if (NON_CAPITALISED_REGEX.test(precedingThreeChars)) {
       const autoCapitaliseMatch =
         precedingThreeChars.match(NON_CAPITALISED_REGEX);
       if (autoCapitaliseMatch && autoCapitaliseMatch[1]) {
         const capitalisedChar = autoCapitaliseMatch[1].toUpperCase();

         const contentStateWithCapitalisedChar = Modifier.replaceText(
           contentState,
           selectionState.merge({
             anchorOffset: focusOffset - 1,
             focusOffset: focusOffset,
           }),
           capitalisedChar + chars,
         );

         EditorState.push(
           editorState,
           contentStateWithCapitalisedChar,
           'insert-characters'
         );
         return 'handled';
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Some other notes:

I used the `test` RegEx method to check for strings matching the auto-capitalization pattern rather than `match`, seeing as this is an operation that will be invoked every time the user presses a key and `test` should be faster than `match`. Although it probably won't make a difference to UX unless you're dealing with really long documents.

*edit: in the original code I posted here, I forgot to define `precedingThreeChars`. Just add it in like this `const precedingThreeChars =
    getCharsPrecedingFocus(contentState, selectionState, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { EditorState , Modifier } from "draft-js";

  const Insertcap = (chars, editorState) => {
    const UpdatedState = Modifier.replaceText(
      editorState.getCurrentContent(),
      editorState.getSelection(),
      chars.toUpperCase(),
      editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle()
    );
    setEditorState(
      EditorState.push(editorState, UpdatedState, "insert-characters")
    );
  };
  const getChars = (contentState, selectionState) => {
    const currentBlock = contentState.getBlockForKey(
      selectionState.getAnchorKey()
    );
    const currentBlockText = currentBlock.getText();

    if (currentBlockText.endsWith(". ")) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!currentBlockText) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  getChars(editorState.getCurrentContent(), editorState.getSelection());

  const handleBeforeInput = (chars, editorState) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const selectionState = editorState.getSelection();

    if (getChars(contentState, selectionState)) {
      Insertcap(chars, editorState);
      return "handled";
    }

    return false;
  };


  <Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    onChange={setEditorState}
    handleBeforeInput={(chars, editorState) =>
      handleBeforeInput(chars, editorState)
    }
  />
```